# Kendo treeList data source- not expandable

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a data source with following structure:

```js
[{
    Examined: "N1"
    Duration: "04:28"
    EndTime: "2015-09-16T08:04:28"
    Uid: "1.3.6"
    _events: Object
    _loaded: false
    dirty: false
    hasChildren: false
    id: 1
    parent: ()
    parentId: null
    uid: "76b1cc5e-cb17-41de-8792-478d31b5c41a"
  },
  ....

  {
    Examined: "N2"
    _events: Object
    _loaded: false
    dirty: false
    id: 61
    parent: ()
    parentId: 1
    uid: "49b5f851-447c-41b4-ae6c-d9332b461e82"
  }
]
```

The second element in the list is the child of first element. When i bind this to treeListDataSource, the first element has "hasChildren" property set to false, even though second elements parent Id is set to "1". What should be the expected data structure?

The code for TreeListDataSource:

```js
scope.dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "id",
      expanded: true
    }
  },
  transport: {
    read: function(options) {
      scope.getData().then(function(dataToBeDisplayed) {
        options.success(dataToBeDisplayed);
      }, function(error) {
        $log.error('...');
      });
    }
  },

});
```

The parent elements are displayed in the treeList, but not the child elements. Can anyone help me find what is the issue with data?

Thanks.

Comment: could you please provide data, which you will get in 'dataToBeDisplayed' object.

Comment: What is "parent: ()"?  If you remove that it seems to work: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UpeRo

Comment: @ezanker: the property parent: () is getting added on options.success(dataToBeDisplayed). When i check the value of scope.dataSource.data(), each array element has property parent: (). Any idea how to prevent it from adding? The data source i am passing does not have parent: () property.